# jQuery Tablesorter 2.0 parser undefined

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have jQuery tablesorter 2.0 plugin. I have no data to display initially; however when I run the form on the same page I have data and no error. How should I reconstruct this? Here is the error I am getting:

> TypeError: parsers is undefined. 
>   tableSorter-2.0/jquery.tablesorter.js
>   Line 483

The table cells are not getting built because I have no data until the form is run.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sortableTable1').trigger("update");
  $("#sortableTable1").tablesorter({
    sortList: [
      [5, 1]
    ],
    widgets: ['zebra']
  });

  $("#submit").click(function() {
    if (!($('#submission').attr('checked')) && !($('#fedBook').attr('checked'))) {
      alert("Please select any(or both) of the checkboxes.")
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  });
});
```

Comment: Is possible to hold off on initializing the plugin until the data exists? Like after the form is submitted?

Comment: How would you suggest this be done?

Comment: Well I am not familiar with the plugin but how does the data get populated when the form is submitted? I don't see that in the code you posted. When ever you add that data, directly after it being inserted into the DOM is when I would initialize the plugin. I would need to see more of your example to say exactly how I would do it since I don't see how the data is inserted to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

The original tablesorter (v2.0.5) throws an error when an initial sort is applied ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/1448/))

It might be best to apply the sort after content has been added to the table.

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
  // ...
  var newContent = '<tr>...</tr>';
  // update tablesorter
  $('#sortableTable1')
    .find('tbody')
    .html( newContent )
    .trigger('update')
    .trigger('sorton', [[[5,1]]]);
});
```

Alternatively, I have a [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), in which the issue with the parser does not exist ([demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-empty-table.html)).